# No rule to make target libmysql.c', needed bylibmysql.lo'. Stop

Tags: linux, mysql, gcc

I install mysql5.1.53, run #./configure is well, but run #make have this error.

My system is centos5.8, gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)

```
make[2]: Leaving directory /root/soft/mysql-5.1.53/libmysql' 
make[1]: Leaving directory/root/soft/mysql-5.1.53/libmysql' 
Making all in libmysql_r 
make[1]: Entering directory /root/soft/mysql-5.1.53/libmysql_r' make all-am 
make[2]: Entering directory/root/soft/mysql-5.1.53/libmysql_r' 
make[2]: * No rule to make target libmysql.c', needed bylibmysql.lo'. Stop. 
make[2]: Leaving directory /root/soft/mysql-5.1.53/libmysql_r' 
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory/root/soft/mysql-5.1.53/libmysql_r' 
make: * [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Welcome, please be careful with formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is anything specific that we can do to help you as all we can see is that your makefile doesn't know how to make libmysql.c which is a dependency of bylibmysql.lo.

If you are following some instructions check you have followed them correctly.

---

Unless you have a very good reason to do so you really shouldn't go compiling your own versions of packages on CentOS as you are creating a configuration nightmare for yourself as you have to manually manage all of the dependencies. There are also security risks as it's unlikely that vulnerabilities will have been patched.

If you really must have a newer version of mysql then you should come right up-to-date and use something from a repository like [Remi](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/).

You may be able to get the mysql 5.1.53 rpms you need from the [mysql archive](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.1&v=5.1.53) too.